# Multiplying width of an element to "span" across multiple columns

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make a calendar tool using basic html table structure, and using paragraph elements for calendar entries. The duration of these entries are stored as number of days, in a database.

Basically it looks something like
this
[image]

Each slot in the calendar is 40px in width. Each slot represents a day.
CSS for the td container where entries are placed:

```
td.slot {
width: 40px;
max-width: 40px;
margin: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
white-space: nowrap;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #d6d8db;
border-width: 1px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
cursor: crosshair;
}
```

An entry actually only exists within a single TD, but simply overflows into the others according to their duration (number of days, one day is 40px).
The css for calendar entries:

```
.order {
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
font-size: 10px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-style: bold;
margin: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
height: 16px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #989BA2;
border-width: 1px;
}
```

After getting the number of days from database entry I try to multiply with 40:

> $duration = $data['duration'] * 40;

Setting the CSS in the paragraph element:

```
<p style="width: '.$duration.'px;">Description and stuff</p>
```

As you can see it doesn't scale correctly across
the [containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9LBn.png).

I think this is because of borders or something, so it's missing 2px for each day, making it scale incorrectly.

However, setting it to

> $duration = $data['duration'] * 42;

It's still not scaling correctly. And the problem becomes worse the longer the duration.

The nearest fix is setting it to some decimal like $data['duration'] * 42.3.
But it feels very dirty.

I've tried using 100% * duration.
I've tried setting box-sizing: border-box
content-box, etc on both or on each of them.

Still there is no consistent fix. If it works for multiple days, then it's messy on shorter durations. And the other way around.

Comment: you should look into `col-span` and `row-span` attributes for this, that way you don't have to do it all in css.

Comment: Thank for your input. I actually did build the entire thing around col-span first.
But when adding an entry the javascript has to read the day of the top row in  order to add it to the correct day, in the sql database.

Comment: And why did that not work out? It seems CSS is more prone to front-end bugs than using a col-span algorithm

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't finished typing when it posted. I edited my comment. It has to do with javascript. Also having multiple "job orders" spanning different days with different durations, made it hard when the was nothing to define each day in the calendar. When using col-span it essentially removes a lot of days according to the duration. Each slot has an ID for drag and drop too.

Comment: Essentially what makes col-span not suitable:
https://i.gyazo.com/f7d750388b73c3cf3b3a15da6497dfa6.png

Comment: have you considered using one of the selection of pre-existing calendar GUI plugins out there already, which have probably solved this kind of problem already? e.g. see https://www.sitepoint.com/comparison-javascript-calendars-schedulers/ for some suggestions

Comment: You should always use `colspan` or `rowspan` for this otherwise your markup won't be semantic anymore. Your issue seems more like an implementation issue for me.

Comment: @Fahmi Thank you very much. I guess I will attempt to rewrite it.

Comment: @TonyArntsen no worries. Good luck.